# Print all outputs (in realtime) in text widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-text

I'm building an interface to adjust a file selected by the user.

I want to print the output of the function that handles the file (***def adjust_file()***) in the ***txt_process widget*** in real time.
Currently I managed to redirect the print, but it prints everything at once, when the entire procedure is completed. It's not what I want...

I wanted the user to be informed of the file processing steps. How to make each print appear in the ***txt_process widget***?

```
import time
import os.path
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


def select_zip_file():
    """
    Function for opening the file explorer window
    """
    zipfile_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir=os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '..'),
        title='Selecionar arquivo zipado (.zip)',
        filetypes=(('Zip files', '*.zip'), ('All files', '*.*'))
    )
    # Configura o Entry
    ety_zip.delete(0, END)
    ety_zip.insert(0, '{}'.format(zipfile_file))

    # Processing
    txt_process.delete(1.0, END)
    txt_process.see('end')
    print('Arquivo Selecionado: {}\n'.format(ety_zip.get()), file=redirect)


def adjust_file():
    # Do something
    print('{} Copy done'.format(datetime.now()), file=redirect)
    time.sleep(2)
    # Do something
    print('{} Rename done'.format(datetime.now()), file=redirect)
    time.sleep(2)
    # Do something
    print('{} Transform done'.format(datetime.now()), file=redirect)
    time.sleep(2)
    # Do something
    print('{} Finished'.format(datetime.now()), file=redirect)


def open_app_frame():
    global ety_zip
    global txt_process

    # Create Frames
    app_frame.config(background='#333')
    app_frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=NSEW)
    app_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Button/Label: File Explorer
    lbl_zip_title = Label(
        app_frame,
        text='Selecionar arquivo .zip',
        font=('Helvetica', 14, 'bold'),
        background='#333',
        foreground='white',
        height=2,
    )
    lbl_zip_title.grid(row=0, padx=(5, 5), pady=(5, 2), sticky=W)
    lbl_zip_title.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Button Select File
    btn_file = Button(
        app_frame,
        text='{:^10}'.format('Browser'),
        font=('Helvetica', 10),
        command=select_zip_file
    )
    btn_file.grid(row=1, padx=(5, 5), sticky=W)
    btn_file.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Entry File Selected
    ety_zip = Entry(
        app_frame,
        font=('Helvetica', 10),
        background='white',
        foreground='black',
    )
    ety_zip.grid(row=2, padx=(5, 5), sticky=EW)
    ety_zip.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Title Convert
    lbl_convert_title = Label(
        app_frame,
        text='Converter .zip obtido no e-SAJ em .pdf',
        font=('Helvetica', 14, 'bold'),
        background='#333',
        foreground='white',
        height=2,
    )
    lbl_convert_title.grid(row=3, padx=(5, 5), pady=(35, 2), sticky=W)
    lbl_convert_title.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Button to Convert
    btn_final = Button(
        app_frame,
        text='{:^10}'.format('Converter'),
        font=('Helvetica', 10),
        command=adjust_file
    )
    btn_final.grid(row=4, padx=(5, 5), sticky=W)
    btn_final.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

    # Processing
    txt_process = Text(
        app_frame,
        font=('Helvetica', 10),
        background='white',
        foreground='black',
        height=9,
        wrap='word'
    )
    txt_process.grid(row=7, padx=(5, 5), sticky=EW)
    txt_process.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, text_widget):
        """Constructor"""
        self.output = text_widget

    def write(self, string):
        """Add text to the end and scroll to the end"""
        self.output.insert('end', string)
        self.output.see('end')


# Main
root = Tk()
root.title('Test')
root_width = 600
root_height = 370
root.geometry(f'{root_width}x{root_height}')

# Frames
app_frame = Frame(root, width=root_width, height=root_height)

# Grid
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

# Inicial App
open_app_frame()
redirect = RedirectText(txt_process)
print('Test of Redirect. Ok!', file=redirect)

# Loop
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can add an ```update_idletasks``` call to your txt_widget. The problem is no that the string is not written to the widget at the right time, it is the widget is now showing the updates when you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `RedirectText` `write` function to update the widget after writing to it.

```
class RedirectText(object):
    def __init__(self, text_widget):
        """Constructor"""
        self.output = text_widget

    def write(self, string):
        """Add text to the end and scroll to the end"""
        self.output.insert('end', string)
        self.output.see('end')
        self.output.update_idletasks()
```

Answer (score 0):

If your main window is in (Not responding) state during your process, you should use `self.output.update_idletasks()` at the end of your `write` function. On the other hand, if main window is responding, you can use `self.output.update()`.